# Progress Bar "Not responding"

Tags: vba, excel, progress-bar, userform

I have the below code which calls one of three procedures, and then updates the progress bar to let the user know that the VBA is still at work.

However when the progress bar shows it shows as "White" Similar to how excel looks when it is "Not responding". I believe this is due to the macro working to fast to simultaneously update the progress bar.

I have tried `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` and `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))` however this does not seem to slow down the VBA code enough.  Please also note the userform which the progress Bar is on has Show Modal property as false.

Code I am using below (As well as Screenshot)

Any ideas / tips of how to ensure the progress bar successfully updates will be much appreciated.

```
Private Sub Ok_Btn_Click()

Dim x As Long
Dim i As Long
 i = 0
 x = Userentry.Value
Unload Me
Dim pctdone As Single

 'Display your Progress Bar
 ufProgress.LabelProgress.Width = 0
 Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")) 'sleep to let progress bar show
 ufProgress.Show
 Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")) 'sleep to let progress bar show

 Do Until i = x
 If ActiveSheet.Name = "Other Expenditure" Then Call InsertRowOtherExpenditure
 If ActiveSheet.Name = "Blended Rates" Then Call InsertRowBlendedRates
 If ActiveSheet.Name = "Development Centres" Then Call InsertRowDC

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")) 'sleep to let progress bar show
pctdone = i / x
With ufProgress
    .LabelCaption.Caption = "Inserting Row " & i & " of " & x
    .LabelProgress.Width = pctdone * (.FrameProgress.Width)
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
i = i + 1
Loop

Unload ufProgress

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a `DoEvents`?  As a bonus, that lets Excel react to queries from Windows, so it doesn't treat it as crashed

Comment: @Chronocidal thanks very much this has resolved the issue!! :)

Comment: A note of caution: DoEvents can be over-used and can cause screen flicker, among other issues.  Depending on how long a loop takes to perform, a combination of using the .Refresh method of the progress bar control in conjunction with a DoEvents only being performed at certain intervals is preferable.  For example, if you expect to have 1,000 iterations, you could perform a Refresh every iteration, but only a DoEvents every 10 or 100 iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Accomplish this with `DoEvents` and/or `Repaint`.
Try with only DoEvents first.

```vb
<snip...>

pctdone = i / x
With ufProgress
    .LabelCaption.Caption = "Inserting Row " & i & " of " & x
    .LabelProgress.Width = pctdone * (.FrameProgress.Width)
    .Repaint ' <-- HERE.
End With
DoEvents ' <-- HERE.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


<.../snip>
```

From @Bill Hileman in the comments (some good advice).

> A note of caution: DoEvents can be over-used and can cause screen flicker, among other issues. Depending on how long a loop takes to perform, a combination of using the .Refresh method of the progress bar control in conjunction with a DoEvents only being performed at certain intervals is preferable. For example, if you expect to have 1,000 iterations, you could perform a Refresh every iteration, but only a DoEvents every 10 or 100 iterations.